# Changes wont reflect in localhost while using google app engine

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, jetty

I'm using eclipse 3.7 and google app engine 1.5.

When i make changes to servlet and run it , i do not see the changes reflecting in the server.
Stopping jetty ( by pressing red button on console window ) doesn't help).
If i restart eclipse only then it works.

Its getting very difficult to debug my project.

Has anyone faced this issue, any fix?

Comment: Have you ruled out browser caching as an issue? Try force reloading a page (e.g., ctrl-shift-r on firefox) after restarting the app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Changes in servlet won't reflect unless until you restart your server in java. As servlet code being server side . You have to restart your web server to reflect the same.What you are saying might apply to python, where as in python(being scripting language) the server side coding will be reflected without restarting the web server.

Comment: How to restart jetty mannualy?? i tried with the red button on jetty console window. but still running again wont reflect the changes. :(

Comment: I think you might have multiple instance running.. try using terminate all button one with two rebboxes

Comment: Thanks a lot! U Saved my DAY :). Whenever i click run multiple instances were started. My assumption was server would be restarted Which was wrong.

Answer (score 5):

Change eclipse perspective into debug. it is on the top right corner of eclipse.
Then choose debug window, there you can see the

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Where is the terminate all button? In my eclipse there's only one terminate button... I have the same issue too, I can have to remember to turn off the server, wait a while and resteart the server for servlets to take effects. So annoying.

Comment: there is no terminate all button, you have to select each individual running thread, after that at top there will be one red square icon click on that

Comment: In Eclipse Juno, when you switch to the debug perspective, you can right click on a server instance and click `Terminate/Disconnect all` and it will shut down all server instances.